# Yii2: Gii-generated attributes in GridView

Tags: gridview, many-to-many, yii2, gii

I'm a little bit confused about how Yii2 attributes work. If I have two tables (say *tradition, culture*) with a one-to-many relationship (i.e. one tradition could be present in several cultures) I could use Gii generated code and get in model *Tradition* something like *@property Culture $culture*, so I could use (in *Tradition* view index):

```
    <?= GridView::widget([
    'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
    'filterModel' => $searchModel,
    'columns' => [
        ['class' => 'yii\grid\SerialColumn'],

        'id',
        'traditionname',
        'culture.culturename',

        ['class' => 'yii\grid\ActionColumn'],
    ],
    ]); ?>
```

But what about a many-to-many relationship as in tables *tradition, book, aux_tradition_book*? Gii would automagically generate a *@property Book[] $books*, but how to use such an array inside a GridView in order to display a bunch of books referring to the same tradition?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can modify gii to do this or you can just modify the resulting file with something like this for many to many relations.
[Display results while joining tables in yii2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27957128/display-results-while-joining-tables-in-yii2/27962479#27962479)

Make sure you set up eager loading and not lazyloading as it will make your page very slow.

Comment: NIce! Thank you. But what if I want to have a newline instead of a comma+space as a book separator? `implode('\n', ...)`seems to have no effect.

Comment: it is not \n think of it as html, it must be `<br>` at least and make sure the column is 'raw'

Comment: Excellent! I tried `<br/>` before but it was being rendered literally, so I had to use 'raw' as you stated. Now I should investigate a multirow approach in those 'many' columns, as having just newlines is no good for proper alignment among the results.

Comment: i think a grid from krajee might be able to do what you want http://demos.krajee.com/dynagrid . I usually do not show many to many relations, I just allow a filter for them. In the 1 case i do show it I use DTs to align it how I want, i believe that is a better solution then BRs

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I'll try DTs first before tinkering with dynagrid.

Answer (score 0):

Fiddling with Yii2 API Reference and the solution by Mihai P., I finally used an alternative shorter approach:

```
use yii\helpers\ArrayHelper;
....
<?= GridView::widget([
   'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
   'filterModel' => $searchModel,
   'columns' => [
       ['class' => 'yii\grid\SerialColumn'],

       'id',
       'traditionname',
       'culture.culturename',
       [
         'attribute' => 'books',
         'format' => 'raw', //Needed for proper rendering of HTML tags below.
         'value'=>function ($model) {
             return implode('<br/>------<br/>', ArrayHelper::getColumn($model->books, 'bookname'));
          }, 
        ],
       ['class' => 'yii\grid\ActionColumn'],
   ],
]); ?>
```

Comment: nice one, I knew you could use ArrayHelper in a way but I was unsure how exactly.